# NPE primefaces's orderlist on a dedicated server with glassfish, work fine on localhost

Tags: primefaces, nullpointerexception, localhost, dedicated-server

I launch my web application on localhost via netbeans on a glassfish server. I have no error on the page rankMe.xhtml.
The deploy of the .war on my dedicated server work fine. But when I try to access to the page `rankMe.xhtml` with a primefaces orderlist, I have an NPE error.I don't get it.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.orderlist.OrderListRenderer.encodeOptions(OrderListRenderer.java:150)
    at org.primefaces.component.orderlist.OrderListRenderer.encodeList(OrderListRenderer.java:109)
    at org.primefaces.component.orderlist.OrderListRenderer.encodeMarkup(OrderListRenderer.java:80)
    at org.primefaces.component.orderlist.OrderListRenderer.encodeEnd(OrderListRenderer.java:50)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:202)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:119)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I don't think the code of my xhtml page is necessary but just in case :

In rankMe.xhtml :

```
<p:orderList value="#{waitingList.recupererWL()}" var="player" controlsLocation="none"  
                                    itemLabel="#{player}" itemValue="#{player}" id="basicList"/>
```

In the CDI bean waitingList :

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class WaitingList implements Serializable {

    public WaitingList() {
    }

    public List<String> recupererWL() {
                ArrayList<String> players = (ArrayList<String>) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("players");
                if (players == null) {
                    players = new ArrayList<String>();
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().put("players", players);
                }
                return players;
    }
```

Thanks for reading

EDIT : I checked if it was the good .war deployed.So it's not this kind of problem

EDIT2 : Generally, what/where should I look when I have no error on localHost and error on dedicated server ?

EDIT3 : I also notice other stuff do not work. In my opinion , the CDI bean are not create.

Comment: post full stack trace.

Comment: I have no more on my web browser page. Well I also have the component tree and the scoped variables, you need them ? I'm checking on the log file of glassfish server but i don't find this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restart the domain and it work. Well not perfectly, the list are put in an horizontal way, growl do not have any icon.

Great : X

EDIT : I just realize glassfish need something like 512 RAM minimum, but 1G is better. My remote server actually have only 512 RAM so this is probably the cause of all my problems.